# jQuery Time Reminder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application that alerts a restaurant 40 minutes before the cooking time for customer orders.

For this I have created a array that stores Order ID and Delivery Hour. This array can store x number of orders assigned with delivery hour.

```
HourSelectedList['orderid1']="20:45";
HourSelectedList['orderid2']="21:20";
```

What I need to do is check this array and alert the restaurant 40 minutes before the cooking time. e.g. order ID 1 has to alert at 20:05.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: Are you looking to implement this fully client-side?  Is there a backend application?  Without more information, it's kind of hard to suggest the "best" solution.  Fully client-side, you could easily use a `setTimeout` to fire a function once a minute (or whatever) to check for jobs that need to be alerted on.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear why you've put jQuery down as a requirement here. This sounds like a job for a server-side application - e.g. a background service which can run constantly (or at frequent intervals) and check orders against the current time, and then send notifications (e.g. by email, SMS, push notifications, websockets or whatever). It certainly doesn't seem like the kind of thing you'd want to implement in browser-based code. Have you given any thought to the overall design of this application, yourself? I don't see much evidence of research before you asked this rather broad question.

Comment: setTimeout --> check every 1 minute --> if difference of current time and order cooking time < 40 --> alert!

Comment: Thank you all. Found my solution with a Timmer that checks the current time and compare time difference and notifiy screen